# Java. Selenium. Chromedriver. How can I enable and disable extensions?

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using this code to add own extension, but before load the page it automaticly disabels. How can I enable it?

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("load-extension=...");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Now i'm trying just to send hotkeys to chrome to get to my extension and activate it, but they does't work...

Answer (score 0):

To add an extension and disable the plugins with Chrome:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> preferences = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);

// add an extension
options.addExtensions(new File("C:\\extension.crx"));

// disable flash and the PDF viewer
preferences.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[]{
    "Adobe Flash Player", "Chrome PDF Viewer"});


ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk");
```

Comment: The problem is that the extension is active when the browser starts , but switches off right before driver.get();